# Azure devops' published .net7 webapi using Nerdbank.GitVersioning for creating versions does not override default version number

Tags: docker, azure-devops, .net-7.0

I have a .net7 webapi which is published as a docker container to an ACR and is dexployed as a webapp hosted on Azure (web app for containers).
I have implemented `Nerdbank.GitVersioning` for providing version numbers automatically.
Running the application locally creates version numbers correcly, but when I publish the app using Azure pipelines, the `AssemblyVersion` is not overridden by the correct version numbers.

Nuget version used:
`<PackageReference Include="Nerdbank.GitVersioning" Version="3.6.133">`
Nerdbank tool is installed globally as well as it is installed project-wide using `nbgv.exe install`

Version.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "assemblyVersion": {
        "precision": "revision"
    },
    "publicReleaseRefSpec": [
        "^refs/heads/main$",
        "^refs/heads/release/"
    ],
    "nugetPackageVersion": {
        "semVer": 2.0
    },
    "cloudBuild": {
        "buildNumber": {
            "enabled": true
        }
    }
}
```

Directory.Build.props:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Nerdbank.GitVersioning" Condition="!Exists('packages.config')">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <Version>3.6.133</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Azure pipeline yml contains nbgv script just before building the docker container

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 0  # Fetch all history for all branches and tags
    - script: nbgv cloud
      displayName: Set Version
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build the image
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: '$(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)'
        repository: '$(imageRepository)'
        command: 'build'
        Dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        buildContext: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'
        tags: '$(tag)'
```

result:

```
Calculated version: 1.0.14-g2051b116bd
Finishing: Set Version with NBGV
```

In the pipeline logs I can see, that the buildnumber is updated, but there is no info on the AssemblyVersions
[image]

MSBuild does not provide updated AssemblyVersions
[image]

Still, the published application does not contain versionInfo, as I was expecting either the  `AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute` or `AssemblyVersion` to be overridden as these are overridden locally.
The downloaded artifact does not contain updated versions:
[image]

I also injected the version using build arguments (after updating the docker file)

```
--build-arg VERSION=$(CalculatedVersion)
```

What else to set to get the correct version?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I generated the .NET app demo below and noticed the artifact version was updated in the pipeline [debug logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops).

### AutoVersion.yml

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2  
  displayName: Install NBGV tool
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: install --tool-path . nbgv
- script: nbgv cloud
  displayName: Set Version
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet build 
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.sln'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet publish
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--no-build -o "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)" --configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: Publish Build
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

### Directory.Build.props

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Nerdbank.GitVersioning" Condition="!Exists('packages.config')">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <Version>3.6.133</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

### version.json

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "assemblyVersion": {
        "precision": "revision"
    },
    "publicReleaseRefSpec": [
        "^refs/heads/main$",
        "^refs/heads/release/"
    ],
    "nugetPackageVersion": {
        "semVer": 2.0
    },
    "cloudBuild": {
        "buildNumber": {
            "enabled": true
        }
    }
}
```

### In debug logs

[image]

### In the downloaded artifacts

[image]

Not sure how/where you would expect `AssemblyVersion` to be overridden, but the `AssemblyVersion` property group in myproject.csproj remained unchanged when building the assemblies both locally and via pipeline agent job.

By the way, please also check if you were sharing the correct YAML definition  or if you were running pipeline with the code from the correct branch. Since your task `displayName` is `Set Version`, the result of this step in the logs should be `Finishing: Set Version` rather than `Finishing: Get and Set Version with NBGV`.

[image]

Hope the this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for putting the effort reproducing this!
I've also turned on debug logs and updated my question with screenshots and pipeline updates based on your answer.
For your question, I assume version number will be injected in the artifact, as you've shown in your last screenshot.

Comment: To be clearer about what version related info I'm looking for, these:
`var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var version = assembly.GetName().Version!.ToString(); 
var informationalVersion = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()?.InformationalVersion;
var fileVersion = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>()?.Version;`

Comment: Not sure if you have gone through the [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/Nerdbank.GitVersioning/issues/416), this [document](https://github.com/dotnet/Nerdbank.GitVersioning/blob/main/doc/cloudbuild.md#docker-build) and the [example](https://github.com/vchirikov/nerdbankgitversioning-docker). May I know your idea, since you know the contents of your project, `Dockerfile`/ `.dokcerignore` better? I am also curious, if it is possible to build the assembly on the agent env and then copy the assembly for `docker build`? Please feel welcome to share your considerations and answer maybe?

Comment: I was only able to make the versioning work with adding the .git folder to my docker image. I still struggle to understand the role of the "nbgv cloud" command in this case. Again, many thanks for the support!